# Java public class Plane

Tags: java

Hi can someone give this program a look in? I don't understand why the output is `_c`. The answer in the book says "Once s3() throws the exception to s2(),s2() throws it to s1(), and no more of s2()'s code will be executed.". Why not?

```
public class Plane {
    static String s = "_";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Plane().s1();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
        void s1() {
            try { s2(); }
            catch (Exception e)  { s += "c"; }
    }
        void s2() throws Exception {
            s3(); s+= "2";
            s3(); s+= "2b";
    }
        void s3() throws Exception {
            throw new Exception();
            }

}
```

Comment: Can't you use a debugger? Your program is not too complicated to bring you into troubles.

Comment: `Why not?` why would it?

Comment: Following the execution in a debugger would help answer *what* happened, not *why*.

Comment: For future reference, please choose a better title. What you've written there has little to nothing to do with the question at hand.

Answer (score 2):

The first call to `s3` from `s2` causes the exception to be thrown before any of the concatenation happens in `s2`, therefore none of the string additions in `s2` will ever execute. Therefore the only additions to the original string is where that exception is caught in `s1`.

Answer (score 1):

The output is "_c" because in this code:

```
void s2() throws Exception {
    s3(); // THIS IS THE LINE THAT THROWS
    s+= "2";
    s3();
    s+= "2b";
}
```

The first line containing the call to s3 gets called, and throws the exception. That exception then gets thrown again to s1, and is caught. You generally don't want  code to run after an unchecked exception because you will get undefined behavior or a program crash.

Answer (score 1):

Because *throwing an exception* means an error occurred, and that method cannot continue; a calling method might be able to, if it catches the exception, which is why `s1` can tack on the `c`.

Answer (score 1):

From The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf) (section 11.3)

> When an exception is thrown (§14.18), control is transferred from the
>   code that caused the exception to the nearest dynamically enclosing
>   catch clause, if any, of a try statement (§14.20) that can handle the
>   exception

When s1() calls s2(), the first thing s2() does is to call s3() which throws an exception. s2() can't handle this and throws it to s1(). s1() catches the exception and appends "c" to s.